# CRUD Spring Boot and Mysql

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to insert data on my database with a form but when I save the form I have a HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error can you help me please I didn't find my error? this is my code :

`@Controller`
`public class FicheController {`

`@Autowired private FicheService ficheService;    @GetMapping("/fiche") public String showFicheForm(Model model) {     model.addAttribute("fiche", new Fiche());     return "fiche"; }  @PostMapping("/fiche") public String saveFiche(@ModelAttribute("fiche") Fiche fiche) {     ficheService.addFiche(fiche);     return "redirect:/visiteur"; }`

`}`

`@Data`
`@Entity`
`@Table(name = "fiche_frais")`
`public class Fiche {`

`@Id private String user_matricule;  private String mois;  private int nbr_justificatif;  private double montant_total;  @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") private LocalDateTime date_modif;  private String fk_region;  private String fk_statut;  public Fiche() {     super(); }  public Fiche(String user_matricule, String mois, int nbr_justificatif, double montant_total,         LocalDateTime date_modif, String fk_region, String fk_statut) {     super();     this.user_matricule = user_matricule;     this.mois = mois;     this.nbr_justificatif = nbr_justificatif;     this.montant_total = montant_total;     this.date_modif = LocalDateTime.now();     this.fk_region = fk_region;     this.fk_statut = fk_statut; }`

`}`

`@Repository`
`public interface FicheRepository extends JpaRepository<Fiche, String> {`

`}`

`@Service`
`public class FicheService {`

`@Autowired private FicheRepository ficheRepository;  public void addFiche(Fiche fiche) {     ficheRepository.save(fiche); }`

`}`

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/ap-2?serverTimezone=UTC` `spring.datasource.username=root` `spring.datasource.password=BTSsio202223!` `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect`

`server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false` `server.port=8080` `#logging.level.root=WARN` `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` `spring.thymeleaf.cache=false` `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update` `logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG` `logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE` `spring.jpa.show-sql=true`

When I putted a try catch on the function save of my controller it shows this  r_matricule) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into fiche_frais (date_modif, fk_region, fk_statut, mois, montant_total, nbr_justificatif, user_matricule) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2023-03-31T21:43:47.266+02:00  WARN 34108 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1452, SQLState: 23000

2023-03-31T21:43:47.266+02:00 ERROR 34108 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ap-2`.`fiche_frais`, CONSTRAINT `idregion` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_region`) REFERENCES `region` (`id`))
Thanks for helping,

Comment: Hello, please edit the question putting all code snippets as formatted. Server error 500 means that an exception has been thrown. Please add the error log with stacktrace.

Comment: @Mar-Z thank you, I just edited my question and added what it says when I put the try catch on my controller to save the data into my data base

Answer (score 0):

I just find the answer it’s because I had a FK in my table a that references another table b which was empty so it was impossible to insert the data of the form in the table a.